# Missing the Queue Newsletter option

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, action, queue

I'm missing the Queue Newsletter option in the action dropdown on the Newsletter queue page. I can't find any explanation on the net?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this how to solve problem:

https://kb.magenting.com/content/5/99/en/magento-missing-queue-newsletter-button-at-newsletter-templates-page.html